# Trying to get property of non-object - JSON decode

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a problem while consuming an API.

In a response I have an `authors` array field, and every `author` has 2 fields.

[image]

I need to manage the `text` field but I am experiencing some errors.
This is how I manipulate the response to get the author field:

```
 $authorList = '';
 $authors = $publication['info']['authors']['author'];
 if (is_array($authors)) {
     foreach ($authors as $author) {
         if ($author->text === end($authors)->text) {
             $authorList .= $author->text;
         } else {
             $authorList .= $author->text . ', ';
         }
     }
     $publication['info']['authors'] = $authorList;
 } else { // just one author
     $publication['info']['authors'] = $authors;
 }
```

The error that I am experiencing is `Trying to get property 'text' of non-object`.

Comment: Apparently `$author` is not an object. Try `var_dump($author)` to see what it really is. Perhaps it's an array instead.

Comment: What a massively convoluted way to, by the looks of it, do nothing more than join a bunch of array values with `, ` as separator between them … a job `implode` could have done as a one-liner.

Comment: Yes @CBroe, I've tried with that solution that I find a way better. But in the UI I see object values and not strings. So for the moment I'm trying this way.

Comment: Yes, you can not just implode the contents of the `author`  array here - because those elements are themselves objects. But you can use `array_column` to extract only the values of the `text` properties into a new array, and then use implode on that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by @CBroe, I've just fix this way:

```
 $authorNames = array_column($authors, 'text');
 $authorList = implode(', ', $authorNames);
 $publication['info']['authors'] = $authorList;
```